# How to change initially generated title after file build in index.html

Tags: vuejs2

I have downloaded a vue.js template from the web. Whenever I build files via npm the title on the index.html keeps being swapped to the name of the template. Is there a way to change the default title?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your vue.js template? It sounds like it could be a vue-router/vue-metat issue. What does the <title> part of your index.html look like?

Comment: Title part is the name of the template. Template that I use I called virus theme by creative Tim.

Comment: `document.title` ? Or you mean changing the title when the index.html is being generated?

Comment: @user3402600 please add some code so I can help you troubleshoot. Without code it's going to be very hard to diagnose and solve your problem.

Comment: I dont know on what it is that I am looking for. I have tried searching for the title that appears within <title> tag on the index.html page but I just can't find it.

Comment: @AndrewShmig the title when index.html is generated

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question - you need to configure your `vue.config.js` file something like this (pay attention on `Webpack` part) - **these files are from working project, so you have maximum understanding on how it could look at the end**:

```
module.exports = {
    baseUrl: '/',
    outputDir: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '../web/' : '../web/js/'),
    indexPath: '../app/Resources/views/index.html.twig',

    // Setting this to false can speed up production builds if you don't need source maps for production.
    productionSourceMap: false,

    // By default, generated static assets contains hashes in their filenames for better caching control.
    // However, this requires the index HTML to be auto-generated by Vue CLI. If you cannot make use of the index HTML
    // generated by Vue CLI, you can disable filename hashing by setting this option to false,
    filenameHashing: false,
    lintOnSave: false,

    // https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/config/#devserver-proxy
    devServer: {},

    // https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/config/#chainwebpack
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config
            .plugin('html')
            .tap(args => {
                args[0].title = 'Ojok Deep Sales Platform';
                args[0].template = './index.html.template';
                return args;
            })
    }
};
```

And after you have updated your `vue.config.js` file, change your `index.html` template file to be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900' rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/go.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/momentjs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/webphone/flashphoner.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/webphone/SoundControl.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Pay attention on what is being included in `<title>`-tag:

```
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
```

After generating new `index.html` file your title should be set to whatever you have written into `args[0].title` option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont have vue.config.js file. I do have .eslintrc.js with no references to the title. The temlplate that i use is here: https://github.com/creativetimofficial/vue-material-dashboard

Comment: @user3402600, you can create one `vue.config.js`, docs: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config

Answer (score 1):

I'm still new at VueJS, but here were my findings. I'd love any suggested options or improvements. I went with option #2.

Option 1: set for Multiple Pages mode
vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: 'src/main.js',
      // template title tag needs to be <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
      title: 'My Website Title',
    },
  }
}
```

Option 2: titleMixin (referenced from https://medium.com/@Taha_Shashtari/the-easy-way-to-change-page-title-in-vue-6caf05006863)

**titleMixin.js** added to mixins folder

```
function getTitle (vm) {
  const { title } = vm.$options
  if (title) {
    return typeof title === 'function'
      ? title.call(vm)
      : title
  }
}
export default {
  created () {
    const title = getTitle(this)
    if (title) {
      document.title = title
    }
  }
}
```

**added to main.js**

```
import titleMixin from './mixins/titleMixin'

Vue.mixin(titleMixin)
```

**Use in Component Pages**

```
<script>
  export default {
    title: 'Foo Page'
  }
</script>
```

**Use in Vue instance with a function**

```
<script>
export default {
  title () {
    return `Foo Page — ${this.someValue}`
  },
  data () {
    return {
      someValue: 'bar'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Note: After changing config as in option 1 we need to restart the frontend server.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1:

Edit your `/public/index.html` and replace this:

```
<title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
```

with this:

```
<title>Your Title Here</title>
```

### Option 2:

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.plugin('html').tap(args => {
            args[0].title = 'Your Title Here';
            return args;
        });
    }
}
```

**/public/index.html**

```
<title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
```